# How to get rid of empty transparent areas in a PNG image so that it conforms to actual image size?

Tags: ios, graphics, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a series of images that I would look to loop through using iOS's `[UIView startAnimating]`.  My trouble is that, when I exported the images, they all came standard in a 240x160 size, although only **50x50** contains the actual image, the rest being transparent parts that are just taking up space.

When I set the frame of the image automatically using `image.size.width` and `image.size.height`, iOS takes into images' original size of 240x160, so I am unable to get a frame that conforms to the actual parts of the image.  I was wondering if there is a way using Illustrator or Photoshop, or any other graphics editing software for me to export the images based on their natural dimensions, and not a fixed dimension.  Thanks!

Comment: Using Photoshop, Image -> Trim... -> OK will default to trimming the off the transparent parts of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of vector graphics and thinks *everything* in the world should be vector ;-) so here is what you do in illustrator: file - document setup - edit artboards. Then click on the image, and the artboard should adjust to the exact size. You can of course have multiple artboards, or simply operate with one artboard and however-many images.